# Show that this defines a norm on $\mathbb{R^n}$. State and prove the Holder and Minkowski Inequalities for this norm.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For a point x = ($x_1$, $x_2$, ... ,$x_n$) in $\mathbb{R^n}$, define ${T_x}$ to be the step function on the interval [1, n + 1) that takes the value $x_k$ on the interval [k, k + 1), for 1 $\leq$ k $\leq$ n. For p $\geq$ 1, define $\| x\|_p$ = $\| {T_x}\|_p$, the norm of the function ${T_x}$ in $L^p$[1, n + 1). Show that this defines a norm on $\mathbb{R^n}$. State and prove the Holder and Minkowski Inequalities for this norm.

I know this question has been posted before, however, no straightforward answers were provided. I know that in order to show something is a norm, we need to show the four conditions. However, I don't know how to do that in relation to this problem. Any concrete steps/answers are appreciated.

Comment: What are your problems? What have you done so far?

Comment: Honestly, the step function confuses me. It's difficult to see what the norm is when a step function is involved.

Comment: This is pretty simple. The norm is just the usual $p$-norm for vectors: $\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p\right)^{1/p}$.